# How I Can Routing Without Primary Key In Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

in my model i have:

```
    public int NewsID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

i want routing with "Title"

default routing is like this: localhost:PortNumber/Controller/Details/id

i want do this: localhost:PortNumber/Controller/Details/Title

Comment: add a new route config to use title that is specific to your controller. you could do it either using convention-based routing or attribute routing.

Comment: Generally, if you don't route via ID, you do it by "slug". The problem with something like "Title" is it's generally not unique and potentially may include characters which are not URL safe. A "slug" is just a unique string, usually composed from something like "Title", but simplified to be alphanumberic. For example, look at the URL for your question. The part after the ID (39834897) is the "slug".

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest updating your default route config to change from Id to title as it may break existing stuff. You may either create a new route definition for your Details action and place it before the generic default route

```
//seo friendly details route

routes.MapRoute(
             "Details",
             "news/details/{title}",
      new { controller = "News", action = "Details", title ="" });

//generic default route definition
routes.MapRoute(
         "Default",
         "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

**Or**

Use Attribute routing to specify this new route pattern.

```
[Route("News/Details/{title}")]
public ActionResult Details(string title)
{
  //get news item from title now
  var newsEntity=dbContext.News
                .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Title.Equals(q, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
  // to do : Return something
}
```

Assuming your **title's are unique.**